# automatically ssh login with public key

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to connect after login to my ssh server.
I created a bash script on the `/etc/profile.d/` directory.
Before I created the keys. From Terminal the connection with keys is working.
But if I run the command in bash script I got the error

> "Pseudoterminal will not be allocated, because stdin is not a terminal.

This is my script. The user rights are set.

```
    #!/bin/bash  
    ssh root@81.169.137.165
```

Please help.

Comment: The `ssh` command shouldn't be on the same line as `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: no this is copy error. In reality I have ssh command not in same line and it doesn't work.

Comment: Where (file path) is the key? have you tried option `-i KEYFILE`?

Comment: @Wiimm my key is placed at .ssh/id_rsa I can  from command line but the script don't work on /etc/profile.d any help? What about cronjob with at reboot option?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with Ubuntu Startup Applications.

1. Open Dash and search for Startup Applications.
2. New Entry with command

gnome-terminal --command 'sh -c "sleep 2; /home/hakikat/login.sh; exec bash"'